# Rest Assured: extract value from Response List

Tags: java, rest-assured

I have a List returned as response. I need to get one item from list using product.name and tariffPlan.name.

```
    [
  {
    "id": 123,
    "product": {
      "id": 1,
      "code": "credit",
      "name": "Credit"
    },
    "tariffPlan": {
      "id": 1,
      "code": "gold",
      "name": "Gold"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 234,
    "product": {
      "id": 2,
      "code": "debit",
      "name": "Debit"
    },
    "tariffPlan": {
      "id": 1,
      "code": "gold",
      "name": "Gold"
    }
  }
]
```

I use Java8. Here is my method. I got List of Card.class elements. And then I need to get single Item from list with specified "product.name" and "tariffPlan.name".

```
public List<Card> getCardId(String productName, String tariffPlanName) {
    return given()
        .param("product.name", productName)
        .param("tariffPlan.name", tariffPlanName)
        .when().get("/").then()
        .extract().jsonPath().getList("", Card.class);
  }
```

Is it possible to do it with restAssured? Maybe use .param method like in my example? But in my example .param method is ignored. Thank you for your ideas.

UPD. My decision is:

```
 public Card getCard(String productName, String tariffPlanName) {
    List<Card> cardList = given()
        .when().get("/").then()
        .extract().jsonPath().getList("", Card.class);

    return cardList.stream()
        .filter(card -> card.product.name.equals(productName))
        .filter(card -> card.tariffPlan.name.equals(tariffPlanName))
        .findFirst()
        .get();
  }
```

Comment: I used Java8 labdas. Updated Question.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to get a value from response json list, here's what worked for me:

```
Json sample:
[
  {
    "first": "one",
    "second": "two",
    "third": "three"
  }
]

Code:

String first =
given
  .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
.when()
  .get("url")
.then()
.extract().response().body().path("[0].first")
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can but... you need to handle deserialization issue of default mapper becase if you try do the following:

```
.extract().jsonPath().getList("findAll {it.productName == " + productName + "}", Card.class);
```

You will failing on converting HashMap to your object type. It happens because of using gpath expression in path provides json without double quotes on keys by default. So you need to prettify it with (you can put it in `RestAssured` defaults):

```
.extract().jsonPath().using((GsonObjectMapperFactory) (aClass, s) -> new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create())
```

And as result your would be able to cast things like that:

```
.getObject("findAll {it.productName == 'productName'}.find {it.tariffPlanName.contains('tariffPlanName')}", Card.class)
```

See full example:

```
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import io.restassured.mapper.factory.GsonObjectMapperFactory;
import lombok.Data;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

public class TestLogging {

    @Test
    public void apiTest(){
        List<Item> list = given()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .when()
                .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
                .then().log().all()
                .extract().jsonPath().using((GsonObjectMapperFactory) (aClass, s) -> new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create())
                .getList("findAll {it.userId == 6}.findAll {it.title.contains('sit')}", Item.class);
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    @Data
    class Item {
        private String userId;
        private String id;
        private String title;
        private String body;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code throws an error:  The parameter "userId" was used but not defined. Define parameters using the JsonPath.params(...) function

Comment: @WillByers just rerun this test in my test project, works as exepected. Have you enabled annotation processing?

Answer (score 1):

Here a kotlin example:

```
    @Test
    fun `creat endpoint with invalid payload should return 400 error`() {
        val responseError: List<ErrorClass> = Given {
            spec(requestSpecification)
            body(invalidPayload)
        } When {
            post("/endpoint")
        } Then {
            statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST)
        } Extract {
            body().`as`(object : TypeRef<List<ErrorClass>>() {})
        }

        responseError shouldHaveSize 1
        responseError[0].field shouldBe "xxxx"
        responseError[0].message shouldBe "xxx"
    }
```

Comment: Excellent! I was looking for this, thank you <3

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to fetch the value of the id, when product name is "Credit" and tariffPlan is "Gold".

Use

```
from(get(url).asString()).getList("findAll { it.product.name == 'Credit' && it.tariffPlan.name == 'Gold'}.id");
```

Where url - http/https request and `get(url).asString()` will return a JSON response as string.